# What is difference between COTS and Web Services or Services in general?

Tags: web-services, service, soa, cots

What is difference between **COTS** and **Web Services** or **Services** in general?I want to know from Architectural point of view as im working on Service oriented architecture so can we define a fine line between services and COTS?Are they integrated in an application or project in the same way?

Comment: [`Commercial Off The Shelf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) isn't a technology, its a concept, e.g. you can go and buy it today (for a price) rather than having to build it from scratch, which is nice from a risk and schedule point of view. Unless you are referring to another COTS?